# Setting Home Screen wallpaper programmatically has unintended effects (Android)

Tags: android, wallpapermanager

I have made an app that allows the user to either set the home screen wallpaper, lock screen wallpaper or both wallpapers to a gradient color. It runs without any issues. However, there is something that's bugging me.

When a user has a live wallpaper for their lock and home screens, and uses my app to set a static wallpaper for their home screen, the lock screen somehow changes in accordance to the home screen.

This issue does not exist when the user has a static wallpaper initially.

This is my code snippet to set the home screen wallpaper:

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Home screen wallpaper applied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

EDIT:

So this is my situation:

1. User has live wallpaper for Home and Lock Screen
2. User uses my app to generate random gradient image
3. User clicks the button in my app dedicated to setting the Home Screen 
   wallpaper to the user's preferred gradient
4. User should have gradient (static) wallpaper for Home Screen and user's own live wallpaper for Lock Screen. However, what happened is that user's Home and Lock Screens have changed to gradient wallpapers (which should not happen as user only wants to set Home Screen wallpaper)

Thanks folks

Comment: Do you want to set image in center....?

Comment: Have another go at describing the problem, it is unclear what you are asking us to do.

Comment: I have edited my question. Sorry for the confusion ;)

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with your app: Android does not support lock screen only live wallpapers - live wallpapers must display on either:

1. Both the home and lock screen
2. Only on the home screen

Therefore by replacing the live wallpaper on the home screen, you deactivate it entirely.

Comment: Hmm... thanks for the clarification. That's is what I thought as well. But, the user seems to disagree saying that it was possible on another app... That's what's confusing me :)